# What do I do if I'm missing a binary, such as clear, in CentOS?

Tags: centos

What should I do to restore the clear binary if it is missing on CentOS?

I only get the man entry for it.

> $whereis clear
>
> clear: /usr/share/man/man1/clear.1.gz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look up what provides that via yum:

> yum whatprovides *bin/clear*

This shows that ncurses does, so installing it should resolve the missing binary.

> yum install ncurses

Since the Man page is already there, then it may need to be re-installed if yum thinks it is already on the system:

> yum reinstall ncurses

Clear should now exist in /usr/bin/clear

Comment: // , I have run into this problem sooooo many times.